# Rails undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little Rails site with 2 controllers *instructors* and *requests*. The *instructors* is accessible by the site admin only to manage the and manage them (all the methods are authenticated with device). The second controller *instructors* is how the visits access the site to view listed instructors and create requests for an instructor they choose. I'm having trouble creating new requests which should save *name*, *phone*, and *email*  *message* as well as the chosen *instructor_id* from the request show page. I hope that my description would be clear.

Thanks.

## requests controller

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @instructors = Instructor.near(params[:search], 50)
    else
      # Shows all listed instructors by the created date.
      @instructors = Instructor.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def show
    @instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @request = Request.new
  end

  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    #@request = Request.new(request_params)
    if @request.save
      flash[:success] = "Request has been submited!"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something is went wrong!"
    end
  end

  private

  def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :message)
  end
end
```

## requests show

```
<header><h1 class="display-4"><%= @instructor.name %></h1></header>

      <h3>Address: <%= @instructor.address %></h3>
      <h3>Car Model: <%= @instructor.car %></h3>
      <hr>
      <%= simple_form_for(@instructor, :url =>{ :action => "create" }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :name, label: "Your name" %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :phone, label: "Phone number" %>
        <%= f.input :message, as: :text %>
        <br>
        <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
      <% end %>
      <br>
      <br>
```

## instructors controller

```
class InstructorsController < ApplicationController
      # Admin is required to login to access any action on this controller
      before_action :authenticate_admin! # except: [:action, :action] to unlock any action

      def index
        @instructors = Instructor.order('created_at DESC')
      end

      def show
        find_instructor
      end

      def new
        @instructor = Instructor.new
      end

      def update
        find_instructor
        if @instructor.update(instructor_params)
          redirect_to @instructor
          flash[:notice] = "Instructor changes has been saved."
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      def create
        @instructor = Instructor.new(instructor_params)
        if @instructor.save
          flash[:notice] = "Instructor has been saved!"
          redirect_to instructors_path
        else
          render 'new'
          flash_error('New instructor hasn\'t been saved.')
        end
      end

      def edit
        find_instructor
      end

      def destroy
        find_instructor
         if @instructor.destroy
           redirect_to root_path
           flash[:notice] = "The instructor has been deleted."
         else
           flash_error('Instructor hasn\'t been deleted.')
         end
      end

        private

        def flash_error(message) # Takes the of the error message as an argument
          flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong!, #{message}
                           Please make sure you submitting valid data and try again"
        end

        def find_instructor
          @instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
        end

        def instructor_params
           params.require(:instructor).permit(:name, :car, :address, :manual, :auto)
        end
    end
           flash_error('Instructor hasn\'t been deleted.')
         end
      end

        private

        def flash_error(message) # Takes the of the error message as an argument
          flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong!, #{message}
                           Please make sure you submitting valid data and try again"
        end

        def find_instructor
          @instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
        end

        def instructor_params
           params.require(:instructor).permit(:name, :car, :address, :manual, :auto)
        end
    end
```

## instructor model

```
class Instructor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :requests
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
end
```

## request model

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :instructor
end
```

Comment: way more helpful than dumping your code would be showing what the error says. Notice that nowhere in your code are you calling `.model_name`

Comment: Can you post the error here?

Comment: There is no code to make the association between a request and an instructor. You are also passing `@instructor` into `simple_form_for` where you seem to intend to create a `Request` not an `Instructor`. Please be clearer about the error message and the action that triggers it.

Comment: @Pramod at the moment I'm having this <%= simple_form_for([@request, @instructor.requests.build], :url =>{ :action => "create" }) do |f| %> which it didn't return an error, but not submitting the the  *instructor_id* .

Comment: @Owen Thats actually right.  I  I'm passing the *@instructor*  with <%= simple_form_for([@request, @instructor.requests.build], :url =>{ :action => "create" }) do |f| %> But its still not submitting it. What did I do wrong now?

Comment: That's not what I see in "requests show" line 6 above. But can you elaborate on "not submitting"? Where are you expecting it to be accessed in your code?

Answer (score -2):

I believe the error is coming from the `simple_form_for` in the show view because `@instructor` is nil.

You got that variable from:

```
@instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
```

You should make a test making sure that there exists a Instructor with the id that was sent with the params.

Comment: `ActiveRecord#find` will `raise` if no record matches.